# Base64_decode to PDF

Tags: php, base64, pdf-generation

I am working with an XML file that provides a base64 encoded PDF document. When I take the encoded string and enter it into the base64 to PDF converter located [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/pdf) it works fine and decodes to a valid PDF. However when I use PHP base64_decode($validStr) I get garbage back to the screen. Here is my code.

```
<?php

header("Content-type: application/pdf");


$imageParam=array(
  'pCompanyID'=>1,
  'pSysUser'=>'dburchfield',
  'pDocID'=>588690
);

$wsdl="http://192.168.0.31/WSSmartConnect/cCustomerDocument.asmx?wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));

$soapCall = $client->GetDocumentImage($imageParam);
$response = ($client->__getLastResponse());
$str = implode('', preg_split('/\s*/', $response));

$bin = base64_decode($str);
echo $bin;
?>
```

Here is the result when it renders on the web site:

```
�ioz�"�}tzw(v)������{ޖ�^�ig���m���r�j�f������������h���Y��ȡ���0�z+����_�0���隊{-jw�ig���i��0� ���M\��r�j���g��.���"f�y����{���m����u�2��&�g��.���"f�y��[IT�LK���x�����Hؚ����\H��][����Y�\�����Y�S[�H�\�S�ۙH�՚Y]�\��Y�\�[��\��њ]�[����YH��Y�S^[�]��[��TY�H�ӛۑ�[�ܙY[�Y�S[�H�\�S�ۙH�������[�ؚ��Hؚ����[�� M�њ[\��ћ]QX��HH������X[B�'/U�[�̈́���(��Pԩ �LVX��d��Bd�6 +,��{R-��c�XMi������Y�iڳN� �����*�����������=���)� �$�-WyxڜI�0[�Ȱ_�b"���U�p�d�e��,5�YT�����s8듨J4�{�/]m��V�,'�MW�{C)�SM��(�]��Țxq� �JU ׄ�e�c�Y�m� �;�R��4�^�u�pd1yy�0]����4�o��Y>/MK>�TX�;2�ZU�Mv�-r�mGW7~��\�7ۣ:˪W;��nV╌�7�*L��qG �랇��8,�¢h��@�?}b>)#�МXK�؂Q�+����?��9��/�� .�ɐ>�~�f&�;z����@�ɭ|9r�pN����"���M�s�0��{��6�`�S�r]�>ߔ���&4�^s�`{b���w�@"��@5d�;�<.���lA���{��P���b��k�N�5�d�/G�;i���&#(�ӡ$�Z��\�h�"�f�Jƣ��+�n� �W: �^?����Ě���=�ؑ�2d3Ë��I�>�rC��_Cр5�@P��;�5�Q�L@�*O�A�I8v��2c�`]� ���"*F�+�둝L��W�gr�����s�A�7���7枎��o�)����<����Js�[�t��Da�Z�;�^���������+�-�W61���Y��m����6 �[���X[H�[�ؚ��Mؚ����[�� NM��њ[\��ћ]QX��HH������X[B�'U4b��=��M%�F�dEUh-a�4�J�ݮ�8�"L�"M#�2!:�%H�B��-'m�c ��"9@�$ƕH�л� u �L#��eZ��y� Z������}����\}6���c��$�}m���w@Q��FQo�>� ��R�G@�F�`[�����>����L��/1w���VeZ�~��J�a}�w|l�?���p������=&�o>O<���c���W��z�n�a� �#o������АЭ᷄ő�[�?�=(�ׄo�LM^eu3������g�t �h� iK���E�W����`���{#�T�zq� �[ʙm��J71f&ay�׉��b#,���[*��PJ�#���2���*��;�}.AQXF���M�_�0�5�t.܆C�89��]6c�{��D؃����C���m7��$-�LҨu .�� -�(�zm� �*����B5 Bl J����qzM.|X?z� t@֖2�k � ɴ�c:����&�>��#�+����aM�om�o���u$7�w){����"P�xZ�"k��C��m��b�� �XWXR�C�>�.���r���̺���Aj���i&G+ M�aM�#�E�'[ �?6T>Ɲ �9��}�q�#��J���ឧ��FfV"��\P>j�5#p�!S�v�m���_�� Y�Ѕ�R��w��oo����Cd�Y��Y��扴~ٚ4��] �C[����Ћ��w����'��*}��m�'��ݰ�oA����0]�1��C? �o�w�;�c��O�v?��3%{'���ʪ��ǡ=ΉG��djQ��^/�����A3����L&5}���aDaeai�����7Y�/�K3=�z� s9�oK�e�T}� A��C�xp�_ ����+v#��/q���ŤǼ���ט��#������~K��p��{����Ҹ����aDZ���q=�灓� ~���qך:���՞?�_�Rk�#������{+~\~I~V��alD��A� j�jL�&�z �3n�P�����������������r���o��Po���]�E� \������y ��{ ��m�A�y��K������ʼ�r�Bm��rݬ���d#$V��'�4���������h~W�5�_�����PT�>�Am,C^;\�%��]z�!В�Ї�9� �>u���A�6 �V���-����V�3����G�~_?Ǐ�����K�a����,��C���f$��C~g�f�U��S�&�s=|o�w�Ϙ�Zي�\�%{̑��ݢ�"� vl��'�Q��(&�{�ps�SH<�~L�p�ȏ���F�Ƿ����� �a�/�&E��g�)�)3�-�I�EFV�|�dZy��{�����R(-"�%� ��[[����R� Ȏ�Z�K^#7z�ъ2{�� fd�Q�3_��'�C͘��#��X��P�H��9_8�L�¥/���}{>�����1Z��_8�m&0/��ja�^g�;� �Enި�gQې�l� '����j�Y��� �L��c#�[� �=U�SԾ�4�ZW�Į�Ћ��֏#�|�/m�8$����6�_�'����:}�&�pQ($.�Q�!�zY�(&���h?ݸ �@�A�Ӆ��~����Px�O�Fc��_��5t��f�2��5���L8���P#H$y�p��&�gNTZ �<�l����'dp7u�W�w�E�����'"ǉ��=�1_��Y��۰�`���M�> ��{-{!{9H&߁+�GZm��� .A��>�K:3FpŠc*h2u��ƁYD�;�`��"����E�7��H� �*t��o�z0��}R�k���^�m�>��l�|d��t���.��g���5� �i�hbh)��jB^xo�au�[Ty;����:/�3��Aޗ�y�A�o�O�?T����^?z��r9X����1����]UYQN�S1�|��@ߧ��ݎG]��X��^@����MZ�T�e�C0JK/4��]�М92 3A��X�����0����z�*�S��P�~Y�"�q��<�hi�0��::ߚZ4%��ɓ�}!�pM���JOU��䴎�>�\ ��xT���zǟ�p�pΡ�ݚ�+pu�z��U�*`U-�n 탱���!�{�*`ѝN����v���B�|,\���'�*4���ɮ�z�8;�4�c��T*�&��Z�О�[�F�3���Z;~�!ٝ�\����f6�s���18oP��e�lgr���u�j�厦mp�"� .ݻZ����T�徊[���/I/�\=^�1y�8y6��w~�)c߂j���Bè�3��7j�$80�y�p�5�����}�8����s-ݴ�(/���-�F���P���%�}6S��I�������4�Ė�p1/?��IUi�LY���)�B����=�|PR選f��f����aڼ����$Qwj���W�t���XK���@����3+�����Mzi'�(/�Gc��إ+L)�1�T���%����4Z�;k-��/����S�,�t�Z����َ��&#��dӖ��+�&e�:��o�L�%/��3wR����c0ō�����+���8&"t龡�{K={fi�b�}YiU-�]J��)EL��D9c?���v�a�S˄}w'�U Xl� ��l�6����T�'7�Qiۊ�l��_���~t��r� �`c&M{V�ZYp�@�WN�:ﭜ�ku{(#��AƢ,�l3��sE}��݃�����D ��D����i�+����G69u�涀�Z��-�HJ&��Tp���R&�tC��t��=g~�!�ik!$<�܆NGè�NT�qE�t��4y�6�v��g,��kW��a����A���?k�N�z�� �Vĥ_ �+�Pm�4y�3��A�h�;J��kh�Q��Oj���a%�vxEB:�.,�d���[�2��A� ���P~�l��>�l��I��<�,���!U���C�_vx��@�0�&�Aɨe�Vb�ҼQ��ʱF�O`�>��y~��@�[����>*�T���R�:p�6AF��n@֝A�:��5Gt*��X�:�����|�%��c凕R�4h��$L�s.h^m������Φr|:D�1��`�D��eT�R�oU��t�JgKiJS��z�Y3���Op����A�������$��s O�� �1�G��s O¼��G�^F��!��=U� �� Ss�?0�4�: "�BF�0ĩ���+�)&�B���S�p�� Dp�xF�!���6�&�� ��|)��*ɞ���0���ED��0\Ĝ���^�V �t3o(.�Qɢiv��u�Oc����2��ӂ2�+���//�A=Z7M!� �۠��Bhd��] oG���w�F�{ ��EaJ���Wn?>x �YO&��6�5�\`�W:�������,̬�l�l���(��uRN�Ml� |��h�@��A��G�.`��%(]34fh^ݡ���n���)��#f�Fϐ��r�vh�k����5�F��q�fn+����KA�/��^���� p`7^�êG���W�L�ݾ���3�n1��O��:*����F�$^�E�w�H�(�?�E�� �����a8�QaЕ ��(�TAW�RrJ�YfT�� �R�d�D�T���}�N%H �Q��R�J�NP�JB� �A#Q�Q��\�)�� �������k�K�ðw ����_�N.�Ϗ���X~�'F7��[��b4�T��uΪU�C�g.���-�t^黙�k����lVO��}L~��v���G�w�go���u�a=�z�K%Z�3�"�50'S�����,3`�-��>�a��-#z�4(��E�K(�YuEvk�9����"����v(�|-�J|W��i��L����[�b��t P��|�B/�QJ�YK�ȜY��Ju٥����iW_�h���pjq��ˡ ��@�@O���H㢀G���-Z1B��,��O�Q�����f���FY:5��RҚn��h6��׀�.� �K�Fp3�iVR�Ҳ�__��"�˯| �|ˆ ����PWbU�-h�z�V�9�G�� �`c�{�������<��+�L�+ww�U�,��L���)%��,e�b�h./F6ex��b��Ӎ#{[F��v�%��Qk*m�a������=���4���r�#�1Ǥ������7�:�of?tu��}a�*������m��Σ����f���,�����������}X+ |Ɉ�����h�jǺ�W�tQ�^�[��Xb���(���7�!��UhYZ�ZcS2���iT���S��XM�-�[q�v[���J���'� �Z ����p��yq�9ܮ�f&!g����T �(��ů���E�3cݮg=]aBӤ��ڡ]��l��j��}[���U��b:{#]%�����LD�bb��FM|��8��{=��� ���0fnV�� ����lg�q��!�WƖh�xC��hZ���"Zܶ.X͐��5��v}�/2�]p$�GK�!bѤ!��G$�1���j~:��mV�l�Yo�����5�� �f>�q���i������x�E~ ���!`�*+��|������pT��Բs�]�y��-����B�� C�K��C��\���'�Ň��0��U����Q���uZ-=����)��xL.�7C���g���g���9j;^����9a�9k��m��ϹO�EC��f�E���?���������Oyv`��3���ʫɺ�F�*��� �KL�go�kZ����_-iti�$n �a~l [F�#��܏_#�q�NZ6��۵��r��-�G�ö�ݹE8���J���l�C��]�L8�<�2�6�}�~�w6o���5ƺ�m�~�w�dj�S�T�uQ�lЛ��՚u:�),!�eHk���r!ʴ �?�͡E}�c������-�F2��ǰ����`{$��}!��l�蝆l�+�;K�.W8n�oZ�V�lŦ�gmTh �o����g�V%��5g�� ?�ƪҬdq����;����e�~�?(��3�O�Ym�if4&��iv%��z�1�n ���X✋����br �Y84��p@f�0����ܳB�E�9�MW�&1D���"��� ��?�M�?����e��0e�}�S����c�u�9�8}z,t�4�"�љ�V�s��mK�L�m�,�m���-Eh�h������˳:�kk��>�cfqV��B޽�<&�;����x^p�*���ptz=%w��m��m �/�%����P=��{azgst����y���Rǘ��M)���;�1X�����\��/�جn�%����m��}�� D��j� J�2:Ye���gU�(O$���F��3�Yl�nJۦ�k�"n-��p�������Qt��.i���������:�I�m1or\Gp�۟�?��GY��f��G�#�>5�ǯ��ȶ�|��D t\tq��)�����N��s�\]c#���7!c�� (� M�۽����e�=��mt��Z����<�_JȨdr F���2�S��\��-����"pf<@�m��Wu!�8 HTiA�4Y�`ʚZ�Ju��뾞�I�g�B�60�����#D=8���y�E�RY?�}���#ft���o����w�;����K�^n7�g3�`��YJ�<{z=��oX�5�9G'*��s��Ӹ ��bBr{ؾ�"�D�S�tW�z ����Gu�CN�Y�*�_ �\��D�3c U#!$���W3��Rn�P�K9����]��P�TH�r.��r�:�w�4��Nw@i��b1P�gC��<$)V�B��J����� �T�eOfD�XI�^ ��0h�I�oJ��;���ǝ쓆7oEQ _�ǣ!P��:�U� ���27�)hXT�޶8��@ ] d�i�%;PBx�z�R6��wV�b�� �;�+�����?��z[�u� �?sz�;����p�y��_�~�Q�K�ӈ�~�{KD��j�[v�"}�����E=8���� ft���gJh(J�a��*ZD��Wy`�V;����F) VE�r���h�����|��0�U�ԅQMh�,#�L^Z�#�Q���_�v���7HI�O=�' �>,D�xЎ;P�f?%�]f�$4�e�Z�j�t�|��bT��"|bc�4�1�8a8Rq���]H��W��=Q�- ���s�.� �Xi����g eqd�!�^קb����yV[�3�5[v��/ş{O�G�����_���� �w�娅��\"\�ś�n�+�m����c�n�Ե���M�;�L7�~#�J>%�f�y���t<}�� �*���Ub��4�&e�����3�w. �?���d2?j�6[��{�طÇ�z�o��|���/�.��r�.�)J��?{H?p�?]�f�U���h ?� >���a��$3{�*���Qo$��\�����5Y��R��a2��y�#���y�+�� ��@V�@֜hB42��p:+��D����eB�@�~}/U�͸w�oz��G;F7�=)���� ���w��'��Fp�ۻ�7�\���etW�~�֑������@�?J�>Ք�w��(�ϦEmx�x��}D�Ge��1>�v��y�ٵw�v���1��.f�:��,����B��9��,u�����0��p�*�[�\�H9��k��������������y3����@B�(��E� ��V�F�H�*�*� e�+���r�I��0MP�������)��u���["��%�mL����nQF�,� ����2Y#�UP�,ȼ�| �������L۾��0�0���v1�xӶT��#�X���]��Zha,���SRڃGA��(.��N���Ntf�(���'���4&��v梈*��4�Do�1��!��C-�Lw2T��[����^ӟ����䧔�~�%�l��R��V>5��ym�XJ�g[ʏ�������}v���w����5��e'�a�ŝyk�o����z�?c���x�~z�M?�y[�T����JooO;�$����?�'�mx���7��:_p����������ҥT� ��Am��"-"�$�7��,#/ 2g�%��J�)�O�F�r ��)u6�z@.D���VU(�A�נ01��������QOI�DIsM�"o�`��`~�։�έ+����꿰�4��R���c����kNۍ�R�_J=1T�C�s��;ؐ8�.@��/tI�ѳ❑3����s���gͩOx5V�o�ђPib|�K����zOaDi���"*����XXÿ��f�c���E~�mJ���f��G?���FY�n����t�Z���=f�D�ܧ�oQ�[O���1d���ݍL��IT�Y�v�'��;R��"���Q�����YV�X�͂��{qo��J����5�����?�lA��ލ���uU��/!c%� ���o_����\'w��Cs�_���g3P�� �;6��koCzџ�&��z�ǯ�;AHe����Sֽ����T/'�>�?�an�H_������+3;�^H7`�#�7xݮÐ�������Ȋ�����G�'�����K)�Ɔ[�+~��~3��l�:���ξ�8��~д��ӻ����-Y 6s�p.�����x���_Go�܋����|3����1Q�� L���;�!��C��7Q�C�S�=;F���D�\�Z�� %tE�i2���)<� X����i�����k�?U%�����j3y�B�����)��2�3_(�q�����;b����Y}�� ^\g���;���`>��:TD�2ƒ\`�[�V���K���{= r�ЮDX����5V�U�r�S3�P������d�b�*=��v�B6�"� -3 �v�?8�2)G��(б[< ��� .T�<^*���"�"&���C���T�V]$�&(�&��p�ۤ�S���Z!a7��$��� �E?#��v3 b��δ̧9+����Tܙ�l�AN��C<�e|ۇ�]r�S�u&*ԧ�gT��������+oy>�y7U���]~h#?����f��6;���ڃ���}��n�9y�a?a�+�����&��/�`�j�M�5�+���5�5��ލ�����5���&��*>����%[�n<�{}�$4>�~UҒ��>��yu��o}����u� �LB�3Nap�9L�N.X'����^E�l��1 b�Q��g�o���/�_��ti���F��s�\�[�˚��L�U��Y��sqʢ�����L�`w`ֆ�U)t�U[��<��:�0kD�h#v��|����7��T�DOC����wxTJ��Ε�J�F�L�o\�JK��[�@�� ?�=%c��!oy?�nU�_���R���������^�C�u���|����$�b��;�'q����^D���好a�>��]�dL$��<�+�Fi oE�3�Gj���k+~S-�����dԼ��K�����ѓTԐ(�֚֚��c[�B���k�)ޜ�e.�CLƹ�Ջ�:k�8���]S�;+{�zk���)�'ʀ�v��0�����f�4T�k)��[\[QSQ�̹vV�XU�y:� jZʵ��[b[#�ҷWV�oz/�:�S�ߪ>-����Ɨm]Cc[]Ad��>`�T���k>�7�_C��cS6��UN�L�Uv2�}��3�T����0������T:�U+|�wਜ�9&������W�RN5(����Q��@�E��z�T��i�{��e(��̀jӳAm���(��-G� E5����kA��T����Kyy�E1N�ŧ�f��.�T�>�� �W 4�gP�?c���A�8$B�T��\���a���y�}mlf�c�5��[5����L�� �U��W���̾+w�����u�$6S ��E#���9G��ɟ��N�6k���;�<"�9�Q���_)gZ2��>K�<���m��r\�P��'�#qa7��g�փ�4�p&�pe|S1�b�c"�V7[ËŦ���H)(b��P{����`<5M�j��q�@Yad�$��,a������%�z�*�om�{F7K���]�N�hzz[J:%u�zB�>��b`J��^�O熀�?���$[Y���R�&W �w�έK�K%�0V4��X�� ��3~wi�#>p�<ԟ�!�<�aGW�2�?�|���Ej��_�ѻ���^�����p��"��kR#e� �x��;�e��#xĶxP�$��v ���J���{��j��ǆ1�qN}f���I�$�>��u�$q����a\�� ����)�5՝�y.����w��h7GT�^-Ih�c�tX3��O9PkRP�G>��r��+�KU��6�2\B}�_��U��Y��,F�(ųۥR�]y<=��]�1W �8%G�&��N�� dEl�+�R�~]gݲ_^����(@���]�#"��T`zq��$��C|M�� �?M�F`��V�I�|�@?K��1������}D`6g�uCI��H���_I�W E/y�K~�c/���}%���%��'0n�7���)��?���_��ן�"�B����❦ЛyJ��~s���r��7��j�pf;Iµ���J��H`����� �{���`��X�I�����At���{�bI�$j ��fms*9�\�c,֣9�Q�V%r�+K |d7}� �%�/oI�5H�^R��D��MO7���&�u���)/zhb-�-���|�!gK���� ��X�V�gE�gM�u.�T�h>����yYn� F���M��2�p���w���4�4�O� �Ǻ��q66� U!P�!-9/���EYn3�@5����n��_}���)��#�R��%��kCqFR�N�<>VH���OH������D~� G� �C]��+�%�,W��IF�5�QQ (�Ӂk�T���<����K�o��"8��2C�4����A���e�ǝ��:ן|��S�-����^~i��h8��_�����m�v�t�~~a��y~�����u�����-�� 9]߻�{�N���r]L ��K� �7�V�#�wXT�UeLM!��Q�����<����ٍ�۪o����O�ߺ����w��~�|A��[h=�LTm� n�W%��o70)f��:����6 T{��~�� M��o!������ �sc2�p���Rnr%c�{uL�g�ɜr�\�2;�#8V��\���PʾriWC����*Ʉ�k�,TY��J�61<�� �^^��/v��!$�,塑K�_J �t���e�d��R��N4�MϏZ����m��6�>�Tۓ�pM�t���&�,���ϧ�p|go�,YXͧP�C�;}&f暓 ����>x dۀj�N&O�U���U��N�2��/7�Y�ڍl ��s�7����x�7Գ�!"����ɐ��+���������%O����-�����d}�"�σ�2i�y=�����=^�s�{Mh�N�CW�� q�I�V�[�Ffs��k-Z��&4*^��\��_��,6ꬖχ��L���ىy���n��]VJ���Q)�K�0�7�)�&w�U������|�ʋYos���)���ߟ5�lZ�����?�w�q x�I���w�/��V�j�j�#5�CgEX��S�W8�"���I�1��0(�jS|��V+�Xl��de-T��������B z[ <��L���!��e�%N�/IJ��+Ҭ�'�$M�>:R�T�1�����˺�h��;��}�ܦ4�u#�֓��jYǁ��U���:�m���7,}���c� A����{:��п�����*K�R��`໋1n��Jh�=\nR/�Œ���}1����G>K��;��pA�Y���?�wX4��3�%g�K�v}�Uq��gߺ��κ����pK�俳���:;��@���@�YF�{�7�/z����W?@�x��M���7_n�F�K��(Bkm2h#8�L+�[�vD�e�r� ���HJQj��w`N4��[�f:���c�IB�P���]��2�k��w]�����q���m�&"U��Z�VKLHX� �r�&�7��Z�0�����,lv���@���3Gy�ٱ�>WAJ�������]Uж�L��/D����'B(WX�F�:eS��H��sJۍ�m���.��6�w5{�زa�%O_�ZgLb*�Ò��L7���z] �۬]YQ���]\�9M��L���]�2�5f�Q^4�� �#�� �¡�\�Uj5x�x�!�=�Ҍ`��q+��.2.r�+xѴ�c��v�=��{�O���6�s�жbR�ƶ�C��ۜ�鵩�����=]9f�G�J���|�:)�x\0�9�Q��5�ڨ�*u���6w���z��n��������"z+m����� C�_�Y�z�N;s������N��a�R�����p���R�V�A�a�k7���2�a8����ۍ ������q��! +iŋ��6J{��.��ȑxN��#��;!D��R�v��6�҆�ST=@<�X�D`vw���%���l*eᢣ()=� ���s51׿sP���^?~jٻ�*N*�3�D���(��zPu��0n"���3�m���,�^���|�� ��5�؝�_P�o��8��_u��G]3������6� }�%p�2�9��s�Q�����9/��s�s�o��m*ޟ]}gtW���7U�w�ѥ��IR���J�$ ך|�U��p%^M���z��E�2�Q#�n7;pϭf���V�zum��B�:�2�ʮ nvY���o��� ���+r�������(͎�.X�H���N���4�T�݀B��(�(��2�o��J}XIeM"���L�Ry§�]7E��Y���"���)zu5Y�& �q���Imi�3%S����-�1�2D�ڽ1Dr�����8�����p����<�}��i6��R��Fi�נ�V�\�Cx�QϽ*�nsS*���P��?�7����Oy���_�:;+�*�ю�����˝K���W;�3]f��f��ߵ������t����ޥ0{mʖ/�h�y-xYb���� ������A�k���X��ǎ[\)#_1≑7�4�1ؤ�±���W��$s���!���3�� "̍u0iD d�g�0<�`��یe�M�������=s�5T�۷�!���}����]�/��v>w�'���zǟY´��A��D ����A8�5մչôñé؁�a�bbY;}h�Lڛ�h�����J��L���J�:�Y) #7�5�ou�ŗGӬVm�C�I���_vО>� i/K��_�sr&�Mo��MwL&���<�0�呒:�O9�� �&槒S��S��f����-��3a4^#tNwm2m�Q�4�� �m�F4��j�xgd�f�LO�����k�:�tG��1Q�v�D���L���Լ�"d�z�j�it��Hgi�b�|$��d��-�̲0,4qI�곶-���z��*� �Y*�G��jo7�����#�7��N�����]�����-G6/����z�x��?��Ee�6/P��ϥh�+%8ێ��%+Υd�������jv��`�4��c������]Y��K��{e������1�h6�p����� G�ҮΗk�/J�ƻ��\�];\]�Wg�FIΗS�5�b����g�T:S����A6u/�s8^I��)0���ݾ��7������"=xP���KM� �Z�J��}~��Ζ-�g����&�����u��������#�#w�_7�vPê�����ԏ��ע��dҔĩ�c��2E���S;K�fB��M�2������}�p��d`'�>.j ��ܝ��e������bыg4383���� a��f�����h�YkΘ�~!)0�T�_m#��d�7b�)t��,҃���r�R�DaC#��KX��P�E�IfǬ2�x'�(��i�-I׾%����m��E"�E�U���3�S� �S6�6A�sE��gm�45��p�5�fw���S��1�o������w�8���9�q�;���;u�˷��Y5j����.gk*������nx���0�6Z��Y{{cg˷���l���巜��E�<={`�6@|�P����k �������Z�w�e ��Zs3;y�P��c��y ����MlUR�E�����f�{Uzca�^BGٕM����:�I�{>�+��r�|���`��0J�U�����Ȗ�g������.�*aOF���3��\��A44�����# bNNw��'���2���M�����ȉP�lR*̭fLӲ��5|v��q�����]t���fQy�Ž-�O�S�^K��byg�ɤ��Z�n��>3�t3�c,J&�Q��g1k,�d�ϋTabV�"QQ���_:��)c�s�k�{��u�C�C�O�j�S����Y�f,��H��F�V�]���ǭu����]N[�lm�ze�u��C�'��ַ�f��u/�ĥ]�����_d4Y��7��D��S[�r{#�+ ��B�E8��СЫ�(SyhT)7;K�֮UiU�UQ+Ϊ�>��@\$�)d���z�� ������ݭ��AƬ�z�˿��نg�q����Y ��I-6SM��X0�#�B�J�B�9���B5�.R=6�,�,2�8����:9 ���$� D<$]� �-��k�,u�X���ښ�*��!��(�*lB请��o���u������%ଘqBtZ�v�����GFoyR�]SwSQPܹ4��s�/3� b��Z��6 �8�F�k�6D��p� 778�bX����� ��Y�Nڹޮ�-�ĺ����M���/��N�ѽսҶ�IM�k3��D�Ö�<ӎ�<\��?�� F��-��%01� ����oR�?q�� ��4�r�lջ{[hLy�/~��t^��~�ϯy��Oȫ���*i�<��S����p�����w �Ӂ�=2u�/����4���b�G�O�� c��A��U��:f~eEՌ���z2�c�eJ� ĥ� �;�OU>b�)��w�xsy%��K� ��a���W:�f�-}����������z��"s�j��s5h��/�7���[µB�����t�^� �S�)T��� 1�=(��C rM�a��v!A9>�h#D�XR��e�`[`U���� ������x�8{=h�����z�>�]�P��;n�� 4���'�7�m`~����=X �m�����Ŧ����&�^�[�ڟ%i��N6�eA�}�x%�X�w�0�Q� ���[��9'[����F�&�ݱ�����?��Cצ��j<����V�� uF0�F�ҍY,��fօ�B~��e�%�L�n0���#�i� AlYZ]]����C������� ��ע����8�+�V�J���ˎzs�AUo�yO��T}D.��{��j {[+��a?�qs9�����.��}�3��?�2�-���=ڶ��d���}v<Em����pK����z"w:ͳ������.H��۞�SAK~���|f�Ń�xN���מ�d��_��c�ű>�o��I3Yn|GҎ�+��^ۺ�_hq�~�J��B��5a�-jDښ;�����k�mjj��2�TJ�DK�q� ��׍��'SP�V�'g�l��#y��Y̆RC=�� �U[��"(ޥQ[ׯ}# �䔳R�}��h�Ӈh�+Y�;��͑e���p�]v�z��x�8$�Z����B9as��R�4��$��͔ �"�#�����A��]6��c�ϡW�pi��ݫ�a�Z�?�Wpl�A�����Aɵ��0VU�J{��M�P�. ��靰���m��l�R��^���k�z��7�{E�}�� �z+�QXj���앆�j�AjT,�QG)G��C�An�H&�� ��5Z�*�5bR0�5�=t�������݈�N� w[P;�`���Y��2 7 M�j_*��R����А�M��U�e�i�+�U��/�g[��-o�h����4�~�j{�� ��&���.�AY��� G�Z�)ū0 ���H��Zr�!��3�&N���������\�+��b�F�%TP%�B��;�R^n��� @*S����?׀2�iAD@�ېam��Ftk��7�2�T���.;`��ֆ�3L����ٴ��[������o�7{��֗�I�֯������}�v���Z0�z[ ,�k�뿎=��ͻ����1�{��SO��PG������}jMG#ԓU�P�Do�-Q�Q�B�]Kߔ-E�qs�9��h��m��Uh�����c)�ܮ�8�r�����< gc�쬽�"X�_U�{{n��ZQ�<߻� �����i���E��Z�+��C�2���zip��36R!�*���h�\��-�pزǣq���va�j=ۜ1wSV~���I�I��NL�U�X�z`&Oh[��������/�C](6�Ɛ���m�+u�D����W^��Fw�Ri��G���t�l����OX��A���]����G�wi^6SP�T&�!��t��( XB0S�e)P�̔� &D���_�tޤ������L't_nΧKV���o����SH������{���?�^���\�S��},}!�I��5�*�W�D�ql];ktt�}�d�r����X��>v�u�����S@�$;�hAݚ+�v{S��dύ�ȳ�"*�#'�Q��tl�-�x�1�,��M���rFo�{��E�(O�])�ԗ&Z���*�7�ݢ�EeK�9CȈ�(��"���l5:Ŀ��"��/�(t �z$6�uU��U��� >j����^,�&z&�!��XM�c1�� 'N��ˤ �bZ�n��00�w)zTvN�e� �]��4����1qH!�¬���钱��,��[�8���R#��=���D���B� �H�A-�Q��N�-ft[�����K���dXpF�� M(��]�1�S����r &����!�g�oo����P�?#ܕg*������[�� ??u3�]�� P�[l�D_-�K��OG�P]�� X�K�o]�L0�� _!I�{cDk���|��B�t�E�W����6�g�ǰ��Ub;k<,P ���f��ʒĢ�htI�;�cL����"��C 5�CF3�I��{���($�]_�.\$�X�9��s�d�W$�n�~��İ�3�� �@\��)J�֠�CkCx0�@�5�����)(�@#�0jdR��*R���@1Z9�:�ն�找�]��[��NY$А��Ï�΍����5lਪ�C���_2�q7��ށ�����ի6!�;>�of�u �ൔ�&�����Q`�qb�?�v�n���,�_�ҝ*M�f���6���o�������2>�M~�Z��b�g��?c��I�J���x�▅�~֤��-�Ï�w��it^y a��1�óJpWL��������0���#��<>A�M�`Rv� �OS� kQx�O@ �ȅX�^䊕0x�� ��BE���;V�T١��:���x�B���N0M%fr�4�k�g�V�jv ���j��Y����!Y�S�3�'���rz���$��P�t/n�����E��+L. B�����W˩9[�Q�UԞ�� MP e<$�z �W%K�Z����#�\�(G}1l ~9�1ĝ�l�w�m�G8�����G�O[�f����V9���-�*ձ�6�|2����dh 5 T�����h��L<�)dq��͝֌��SZ�}$����P��ڎ�p �k:�>�fg��^���>� +n���_0-ӓ�P���G��R��~8����v�"���V��l��0��L�"�0��m���Y�b���7]��G�Z%(���p��w�b������B���3�AXV���G��_���¹�eΈu�c�nn�]'o�R�+)���m=D3?X�1e�����v�afuf������N5e��3� "_q������|�SE��9��Ǝߘ5�yyZ�؂;s9�Aǯ>4~�}�ٷ�B�����v���퇽�Y�{�F�6R�q*�~�?Qޥ�Q/�o����A�'�4��o��Y4�I�T�f��r�Ҏ��^eh+r0�ҧ(���u����.�a��s0��O�)������K����n���}��?c���4p�:-�CE�)M��R�S�6���)��N�1��8����ڂ���G�T�}��=P`��U�z���ò=*N0h�"��r\����& �[��O�bS�6��{�qiʃ� �AqrXn�ٱ>���1��kt ��m1��UE�R�e���|�"���["��Q1��CT6v���j #Dz���Cn>��ց&�!�q�XX�%ab�gf[�#^���H��n�U��It�Iw�6F�H�����{�.O�n~reRy�>�c����ѶrbL]�=��I��7|��)&�LeMF*�P�H_�f���K+� �Mo��l5Y׃CIj�k��p�N��c@ZBj�o�/ƚ�����19��]�l��H�����2��/E��f���Zi����3��)��.�(�tC���l{l�K���N���n�_a�Y�k�B���A.y�קh���*��U��Q=��+y��+&hY����F��F!��kɇ�R�������K��~�@�0��V�H�K=O�6{@O��U�v�0��k����6j��fym���ꗴ�r��õWV��U��֘���,��`���/�u�z����)ն!O�B1�l� ��]��8g~�Cyim�.�G}z�(7�a7�P�:�J�,�y�lW�F$���sK�j'0>�*h,R����I6v�U�|�~rΧD��9�H�u�� �D��J�=$�o�7ːk��~�`qD�,�_3�H"����f ��*5tq�ދ���>g�0j��_� �^<�y��r��LJ��X]LK���fB,yFб]����Њ�얓kRu�k7����̲�װ����u�tX�a�=��>�i7��vj��v: g@pV��1V��>��ի�"�ig���}ɝ�}��{��a���æӸ�o�}�������_~��1t�5Y[���X[H�[�ؚ���ؚ����\H�Y�\����Y���H����[�H��YYXP������ܛ��� �����[�ؚ���ؚ��� �L� �L�H�[�ؚ��ؚ��� �L� �L�H�[�ؚ���ؚ��������] ���ћ۝���L�������ؚ�X���[Y�H��������[�ؚ���ؚ������^�[XY�P��[XY�P��[XY�RHH�[�ؚ��ؚ����\H�Y�H��\�[����ԙ\��\��\� �����۝[��� H�H����[�ؚ��Hؚ����\H�ؚ�X����X�\H�[XY�H�Ә[YH�[Y���[�� �M�H�њ[\��ћ]QX��HH���YM���ZY�L M��К]�\���\ۙ[�����ܔ�X�HL�������X[B�';wtZ��<��$ag%�$�7 �`P���q;���@�az�^����=���d�!7vÆ�81�H�7bGI�-*��M�L��MߔF��UIrR^���:R5om뒸�����y햀0=�����m�ϖ6��z#���>��q&?��x|�N�յ��������u-�wM��4D��_��]��o{׮�gW���v�8�t��/�N���mHW�����NG����������^��K���������s`�Fx!�<����R���B����t���:8$h���������L����(NL�����U*����K�/Tf�WŐ��ja ߤ�"hLN�-�}ãc'g���Ԕ���}٬⥑�[���(� ��o8�gɾ��'S�TǕ^ˑ�7�#���n~E���oQv�pV����}�����}��5�?�.EnY��q6`L����s��ji��-E����HM���ΰT��R�[���&�h�}��_���ɞ�Y��7>����UGw�����r��L�o� ��fC�mm�4g^�ᜎ3-�����3i����m[��{�}E ��m�v�)]�Ihܘ�æ*��?D1���ʆ��ͯ���?ިT�io����޸p_]*o���w~ԁ#;1��+�f��[���u�h��a��s�"�Pw���#e��kY��.6;���>��Va��?{�t:&��j���F�u�şqc��N��oI[{��r�4D7���,�hoh�ctآ3���K��{�6��Y��������0���������r�Z��������) F�Ò5�%��m���E�'\wϣ=�&R������/�3�����~��݄��-~�3�ԟN!;�?�kwXh��:F�}���4vu��:Y ��]O1 ���T��{0�]��e7�<Л�0�V��m��Pq\�?�նGd+��?�{�Je�G���_��m��2�Y��W��Z�99�4피�Ɗ���ۆ������``�� :�QKC��ى����-w��h���F��ΛmU;�@����������`.�L��\/�gV���=��? ���}3��*����_�f �:y��)�ד����&[��,�#�J��{ ���w��Ы:����#�F���;���f��Z.xmM����3��Y͎%؆2����L�#^Iy���'�t�_�ql7����������=��ܹT�K�CD�խ��Bj8�_?�N�M'�y��h��k'�'��ꤘ���Ő��������K�q�'����L;;�����e6���z��� ���=��lN��Ow�m���!��x�|0������3.�eN�|�ejNE��{�9't���������������V��M�S!o\�v��RW���v[e���-7�)���%pje�o��L�1����GU������ ����^�����;�x��î-�D�Y�M��֣�&{�,��<]�o&n�#��հ�g�>>�����iֶw��]IgknfF=�|��a1l6�C�k�?rA���錡�P��t�u& ��*&cjR&s?U^ч!��6���wN~�ЎB�[L�t���c�>�S���[��@�@��S�� ����l���:fM�7�L؉��[�����'�g�����bJ��������ܣ'ze��Cr]��s�x���ћ1�Eܤ�ʹnZ�iu=��u �8�G�=�_��d�BXXXS���ϵ�������_O�$�����^����^��fE�/V��4s�m��8[�EN;Y�7��w��h[����=F����?���#?�4����ua&,��T�N$��;Hr�b�|��ԛ%�{�۞d������ܢ#`wl6� �����[��?C������'d�_<�ֲ����<��s�d>�;Ỳ�eU�#F&��p��!s�֎��WS�Le������tS�{�9#g�]�}=��ЖC=U�l����o[n_�t`����f�}^Z��b��2��2�vUϙ`=l�]W{�նɮ��!q�\��2�y�֦��}������M��+�7��^�\��ݤ�{��˝!�Ԯ�������Y#�����y�U V^EƛL�Uz�$���Ԟ3e�x],�p��N������t��3U�z����:�I���]����X,�H��g��ӧCyiN��&���#���j�c���V���G3���r��{���nY��d�בv9td�.��{�ڋ�G��\�yw9�!�>�ӱ��yw]@���X���9}�ܩu�t:U�Mr9�O*.����F���o� �S�CG�q_?��s��S���l܂�����47�D�@���S��G�i�($d*�жj嗏���#��,���|}ٰ����E�sj����Op�u�w ��zi"% ��|�N�J��Tk�suz�}�׷���1����>�ɱ�ၮ��Y�ʕ�27���]i�{�ޙ��3g��%�Y��=�ޜ���)�[Ò���;�{�GƦ�'�X�;�pN�˱;��j�.l�[�-:�}���c���������_-1�ͷ�;RY��ň��pu���Tg����epֲ=��]�'cU���~��d�T��-bz�щ�����Qcp��}���Ų���!}��;����J�˝��}�Yzo����ɐ�9��)�_���(4W�/nN�nz���A���O.\�ϚwC>G��\�u��K�}�G�۟�bq������w_��y���]��כ�$���wRKٜ��/�|�����c��wA��6�˟��xA݈��iƨ[%xǌ��g��֫s��%���=��������ڙ���h������s���L��6�˱���L�DL����< �T��pH������QV�R7nݿ{�����x6���./��<����☭�h5�y�6�Q4�����Ѫ�כ�%X��?�O��y�4Lό���pg7����_��_ �\y>:n|�^YBo�ݹ���J澹��?�0:L�r��T��ٺ�{�n�{�3@͈M�������K�N����6�]��*�f��s��0<^VWg���0,�w��� ���ɖ\�7�/]��[Y��pwv���k��@<^�,f[7�o6�������(�����ov�ۛ�le]��;G�7�_է��v�_˱!j���܂��'���q���w65�V�����}������C�{��\�����vVT:[�)���q���%���Os#�1d��@��Dў⧸�$H�_yX�A⨩�����C��N�w�/�����g5�7O����2;�#�M����e���X�9�4d����M���ݏ�#��f�o�'�%S��v��.D�������z���\�l6T'�J���F��L_��Z'��4�=?-����Ѻ�~�;��Lt�5���r-֣����y���o��! �F�H�o�y��m�/�ooϥE�sc�b�}�����/�ɏ���,�U��M��=����˼�?�*�����BT����̆�������*((�?ؗ�8�u�_?6^?��a_5�^Is��.�[��W�]�'�� ��ɗí]������.�k��w�����R�q�!�oJ���$��$T)b�ggmا3���\I1r���J�ê�sy_<<\L��X��0\Mkɍ���9��{�����Nf;g{qN�{���#U�����כ7c8�jXE���:�W7�o7>`��p'���go��3"�S����r�u��qgf8�K���Ջ�e÷��؃�"��rG�j|�j�a���Cb+'W�����ee���n����W��X���Cl��og;��e@�5��`�1R�>�����1z��.'��]����W���1��/���Ćb���� RZ�2c����P��i�E���Ʃ����^n�k\�/q���L��� t�D��0�us����&Yj�(�i��//l�i�e�ykO/z�L�K�T�l6�VM�G>Q� �>[�����Z�^ U�/��r�N �#�����#?���Ir���ܤڏ�r�^9 q����Ǌ� ��jh}�&W֞^c�o�/~�to��7���8�cq��߁�6u(���o/NMu�\IK�Mt�,ر��մӗ��m&������o��H��Z��9i�m)�+�o�W���T�� ���W�wG���=��#�^ "ì~�^�' ݽd������������cU�G����������_˷���z�^E�i�O �ͻ��ח��f��b���w����gWۡ/�)�GU��Kw��q�ԆK�\�H�܋U�X��N O�\������{��r�O ��e~|�Y�yifT�9����3S��ǅ����~����_�a�%�/dv�-n.v��%?X�����;���O��Z��j�]�G0+��]�J��+�������f��0�{8��;�>Ic�����~2��0���F��ש4����������`~q��{ll���qV;�ޙ��gF!�Q��Z��S�\���8�{�޾h��C�q ��/���S�i^����~b�^�]��뺿j���h��13J�� /ľ��j�ꢘ�{�{��C�����G��nf빰�:�t3�k����x�OK��guԠ���e�����4Q�=R��S�f�I��5�j�M�@�^�=Rδ�4O"ko�1_�d��ۊ�9��گ��o���Z^p��y�N��!q�E3��x����\n��Q��8�Q����h�Y�ۭ:'�Eت9�d���#=Ep�Tz��ds�d��%5s�V�Y�˗�3~`g�>��u$Q�3^��h~Q����ۃ�*hhxxtvo+�ڧO�N�G�����6�����ɰ�yNJ��f�����gҝ^R���@�_@��8�sV�y�Ο�,1]&%w�.|���l,Ÿ��t�����Q�Ɔ��lG��?fSw�>5?7P۸z�]���eU�M�=Z�����˻�#���l�[H�n����ثw&'�3�瞜j����1��s>U�U�����sp��XM�N���b�ǭ؞q=�����C�!��X��k;,n����q�`�5��8}�E���z����]�~^5Ֆ}s�U�L67ЯL�i�c�,yɿ�;m��\�g7^Iw������5��������rf�j����m��W~�N{��M[V�M��Ͳ�ul�-��������v�W���!�߯��X�����j��W�����=�z��iֻ)߯�<�mՕ��V��q��8�����#KC�嶟ϗ ��Ow,��ܿ��O�q����VJ�m|t�������'N}�w�93,oq�%~��~�d�^� ��C����=4�����m����{�iU��墟`\;95��ے��_(�R�i<��}��x`jt}i-]:����R����������������K���� ap��ee��f#�l>B�����8ka��2D|�5�Q�X�ǯ_,�|�,X���>�����:ÿ���Ӌ�_��������q(��܄'Jt����k������t����퓯��l}8la����o�=��ϊ�T%-S�T��j���{%iig˯W-'�+ǽ���I��|�e�R��u>�<�>,={����f�堸Y:S������n�}�|Pj���/?9#�iC������#~P�I�aiiS�Ŏ���yTB�U3��G�O6~�=j^JY��崫��eu��܋'Z/e��&�\)fsכ_fS��|]�?1��fX��zs2a�G���D��Ϟ���eyԯ�zV�C����0��ݔ�|� �ǧ2kd�Be��yQ�ךo>��iX��zviC׾��z9O����]+�����ǟfr������g֓ϋN����￼)=uh�����'�&������t>���}�_}Y{� �߽:2U�u�ǩ����k�o��+��+@0~���BV��[���X[B�[�ؚ��Lؚ����[�^Y�]�X�T�Ј�MHLH�H�[�ؚ��LHؚ����[�� �H�њ[\��ћ]QX��HH������X[B�')a����G!���I�}q��u"� ��� 2 ���6k�Y�=���,2�J,������y'T��<�'�sWsݳ�����]˲��������`,^DX@��O�6EȾč/���\���x !2~V�8/���\�0u�%����J�O�a.�3�CW9rS�%�'���I��Y�� *�6/i�/mp�B��ZH��.g|;�����ڧ�y�$������|'Pg�ÿ=Z-���i�B �� E���J��`����uu���~��B�pY�-�<B-f9��!V�_$�7����G�$q�.��Q�7�byپ�I.�@|C�b��|Az�����=.��/�sS��=�e-V؋Y��� �F�q������4��  ikb���6:�+�Fvγ��m+E{&���_��'T�E�vQ�m�BW#��E���m��v���gh��B���֜jb��T� F���.C��(��!ǟ����V!ğ葮�:�w�t�~�_�ɷ�y �|Q��%��vklN���O�{u�[Ү��_�%�$L�T&g޲����oE��[���M� �S�k��&�Y}�Ygɞ�H)��"��S ��Һ��A�I`�q� g9lJO� �sy�6T>g����[k99�����f��[���X[H�[�ؚ��L�ؚ����\Hћ۝���X�\H��YU\H�И\�Q�۝�PPPPPJ���\�Y\��]��њ\���\�̈��\��\�LM����Y�L���ћ۝\�ܚ\܈MH����[�X��HM�����[�ؚ��L�ؚ�������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������H�[�ؚ��MHؚ����\Hћ۝\�ܚ\܈��\��[������\ZY� L��\��[�L��ћY�� �ћ۝���M���ћ۝�[YH�PPPPPJ���\�Y\��]���][X�[��H���[U����[R��]���Y ��ћ۝�[L�M����XY[����X^�Y � ��Z\��[���Y ���ZY�����[�ؚ��M�ؚ���LL��M� ���L�HH�[�ؚ��Nؚ����\�Y�Hܞ\�[ H�[�ؚ��NHؚ��ܞ\�[�\ܝ�H�[�ؚ���ؚ������X�\� ��\�Y�Hܞ\�[ H��ܙX]܈ ܞ\�[�\ܝ�H����[�ؚ���Y���H� �ML�H��M����� �����MH����M�H��NM���̌H����� �����͍H���� M����L������L�͈��̌ ���̌����LL���̍��H��̎L ���NL��̎MH��̎NH���������Z[\�����^�H�H�ԛ��H���[����������\��Y����LM�IQSш��:�g������^��m�g��.���"f�y����{�(j�hw/졪D�����
```

Comment: Looks like you're sending the bas64 encoded string and ignoring the result of the decode.

Comment: I changed it to echo the decode results and added the rendered results, Keep in mind that when I use the base64 to PDF converter I get the real PDF.

Comment: What you have is technically correct and should work - all you need to do is send the proper content-type header, decode the base64 string and send the result. There are other things that you should do to make it more robust, but that's a minimum-viable solution. Try getting rid of the closing ?> - sometimes including that can allow stray chars after the closing to get added to the response and cause problems. As a general rule it should not be used. If that doesn't work, can you post the bas64 encoded string somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When I add back in the content-type header and get rid of the closing PHP tag I get this: "Adobe Acrobat Reader could not open 'imageresponse.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged"

Comment: Perhaps there is content being sent prior to this? Try calling ob_clean() before you echo the binary content.

Comment: I cant send the base64 encoded string because it is too long for this comment.

Comment: ob_clean() didnt do anything either.

Comment: Wait - it looks like you're just trying to base64_decode the entire soap respone. You need to extract the PDF string from the response and then decode that.

Comment: Thats what I'm doing. I can echo the response and copy it into the online decoder and it works fine.

Comment: I base64 encoded the binary string that you posted and there are soap strings in there. Something's not right there.

Comment: The suggestion by @RobRuchte to use ob_clean() worked for me. In my case, I was receiving the REST response with the base64 value of my PDF. After struggling for two nights, adding ob_clean() before my 'echo' statement resolved the issue of the file being corrupted.